# ubuntu 16.04 update error related to chrome

Tags: linux, algorithm, google-chrome, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Unable to update ubuntu 16.04 due to error

> Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest  algorithm (SHA1).

Kindly share if any one have its solution.

Comment: AFAIK; This message is a warning, not an error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Comment: but this warning blocks the update

Comment: It should not, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1-after-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you are seeing is probably just a warning you get using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This is probably an issue on Google end and it just reports the issue.

But this command just check for the updates ... Maybe I am wrong but I don't think it should prevent you from upgrading your packages.

To check if any packages upgrades are available (and then install) them you should run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: @Avkash on 16.04 you may also run `sudo apt update`, it may give you more feedback. But basically "update" does not really "update" in the usual meaning: it downloads the package lists from the repositories, while "upgrade" will fetch new versions of packages existing on the machine (using the list. And install) This should be no issue then, as it is just a warning right? (Starting with `W:`)